# Can is it possible to print to a printer using port and IP address while using the standard e.graphics.drawstring methods?

Tags: c#, printing

I'm used to using the printDocument feature with the e.Graphics. drawing methods as shown below for example to create documents straight to the printer with C#.

```
e.Graphics.DrawString("Packing Slip", umFont, brush, defaultX, (headerBodyY));// packing list title
e.Graphics.DrawString("ORDER NO", umFont, brush, defaultX + 727, (headerBodyY));// Order number title
```

I've been asked to create a document and send it directly to a printer using Port and IP address and I can't find a way that actually prints out the document I'm creating. I don't want to save the document, then send to the IP printer. I also can't use PCL language for the printer. Is there a way to use the e.Graphics.drawstring method or something like it and send straight to the IP printer?

Comment: This is usually done in the "Print Setup" dialog... you would locate your printer in there and send it to that printer. You would have to first add it to your system for it to show up in the Print Setup dialog: https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/faq/929/

Comment: _e.Graphics. drawing methods_ - I wouldn't know any other methods, just make sure you use the graphics from/in the PrintPage method; and of course that the printer is selected.

Comment: The problem here is how to get the e.Graphics.drawing used to build the document for the printer and instead of having it go to the printer via printDocument, send that document to the IP printer. You can do that using the Port and IP address of the printer, but that technique uses a streamreader and writer. I haven't been able to figure out how to put those two processes together. I've tried to save the graphics as a bitmap and save as a stream or convert to an image and send that as a stream or bytearray to the stream feeding the IP printer, but only get gibberish printed out.

Comment: you'll probably have to use PostScript, then send it using windows constructs: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-do-i-send-ps-file-to-the-network-printer/5089701b-0cdf-4690-abf6-b95bd36021b6